# rails routing error 'uninitialized constant'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been learning RoR through Bloc.io and am having an issue with one of their assignments and need some help. I am creating a reddit clone and have run into some routing errors.

I was tasked with creating a new 'summary' model that was associated with individual posts.

Update: I have now nested the summary within the posts routing. Updated error at bottom of post.

Update2: Renamed Summary to Summaries in needed places. Updated error at bottom of post.

Here is the Updated route.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do

      devise_for :users

      resources :topics do
        resources :posts, except: [:index] do
          resources :summaries, only: [:new, :show]
        end
      end

      get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

      root to: 'welcome#index'
    end
```

The summary.rb file:

```
    class Summary < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :post
    end
```

The post.rb file:

```
    class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :comments
        has_one :summary
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :topic

        default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }
    end
```

The Updated summaries_controller.rb file:

```
    class SummariesController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @summary = Summary.new
      end

      def show
        @summary = Summary.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

And finally the error when I try to go to for instance "/topics/17/posts/56/summary"

```
    No route matches [GET] "/topics/17/posts/56/summary"
```

If I am missing any files or anything else I'll be happy to post.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Controller names are usually pluralname_controller.rb.  Even when it's a `resource` in routes

Comment: pay attention to my answer. its resources: summaries, not resource.

Comment: I have updated the post from resource to resources. Still same error occurring. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: "/topics/17/posts/56/summaries/new"

Comment: This route should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You summaries resources must be nested inside the posts resources :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


      devise_for :users

      resources :topics do
        resources :posts, except: [:index] do
          resources :summaries, only: [:new, :show]
        end
      end

      get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

      root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

You also need to update your controller name to summariesController.